# How to write mysql query for this?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want query which output all job_ID whose labor has been done(JobDone)
[image]

I've tried to use inner join on the query but have failed to accomplish what I seek.

```
SELECT * FROM `jobs` WHERE Status='JobDone' GROUP BY Job_id
```

Above query also return the value whose only one job is done.

Comment: Could you show the result you wish to get.

Answer (score 0):

get result using `join query`

```
select j1.Name,j2.Labor from jobcard j1 innerjoin jobs j2 on j1.job_ID=j2.job_ID where j2.Status='JobDone' GROUP BY j2.job_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the query you have in mind:

```
SELECT j1.*, c.*
FROM jobs j1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT Job_ID
    FROM jobs
    GROUP BY Job_ID
    HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN Status <> 'JobDone' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
) j2
    ON j1.Job_ID = j2.Job_ID
INNER JOIN Jobcard c
    ON t1.Job_ID = c.Job_ID
```

The subquery aggregates over `Job_id` and asserts that every status is completed.  This subquery produces a set of IDs which is then used to determine which full records to select from your table.

I also included a join to the `Jobcard` table though you are free to remove it if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT Job_ID FROM Jobs WHERE Status LIKE 'JobDone'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  a.Job_id,a.Labor,c.Name
FROM `jobs` a
   left join Jobcard c on a.Job_id=c.Job_id    
WHERE not exists (select b.Job_id
                  FROM jobs b
                  WHERE Status<>'JobDone' AND b.Job_id=a.Job_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the name from Jobcard table also, use below query:

```
SELECT * FROM JOBCARD JC
JOIN JOBS J ON JC.job_ID = J.job_ID
WHERE J.Status = 'jobDone'
```

And if you don't want to get name, no need to join tables, use below query:

```
select * from jobs where Status='jobDone'
```

Comment: I tried it but it return 1 2 and 3 job_id as well :(

Comment: What do you want as result?

Comment: Do you want job_ID => 1 only and Status => jobDone?

Answer (score 0):

You should get through :[Join with sql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html)

anyway here's your answer..

`select job_ID from JobCard Inner join Jobs On JobCard.job_ID = Job.job_ID where status = 'jobDone' group by Job.labor`.

Comment: I tried it but it return 1 2 and 3 job_id as well :(

Comment: so what you want as result?

Answer (score 0):

Simple as:

```
Select jobcard.job_id, jobs.labor from jobcard 
inner join jobs on jobs.job_id = jobcard.job_id 
where jobs.status = 'JobDone';
```

Note that what you've wrote:

```
SELECT * FROM `jobs` WHERE Status='JobDone' GROUP BY Job_id
```

does not show the full list of jobs that is done, because you are grouping by job_id. The correct to your statement would be :

```
SELECT * FROM `jobs` WHERE Status='JobDone'
```